# loop over list of list python

Tags: python, list, loops

I faced an issue with my code where the loop stops running once it removes the list from the list of list.

```
data=[["why","why","hello"],["why","why","bell"],["why","hi","sllo"],["why","cry","hello"]]

for word_set in data:
    if word_set[-1]!="hello":
        data.remove(word_set)
print(data)
```

My desired output is

```
[['why', 'why', 'hello'], ['why', 'cry', 'hello']]
```

but the output is

```
[['why', 'why', 'hello'], ['why', 'hi', 'sllo'], ['why', 'cry', 'hello']]
```

How do I make the loop go on till the end of the list?

Answer (score 4):

That's because, when you remove the second item (whose index is 1), the items after it move forward. In the next iteration, the index is 2. It should have been pointing to `["why","hi","solo"]`. But since the items moved forward, it points to `["why","cry","hello"]`. That's why you get the wrong result.

It's not recommended to remove list items while iterating over the list.

You can either create a new list (which is mentioned in the first answer) or use the `filter` function.

```
def filter_func(item):
    if item[-1] != "hello":
        return False
    return True

new_list = filter(filter_func, old_list)
```

Answer (score 2):

Remember

```
data = [["list", "in","a list"],["list", "in","a list"],["list", "in","a list"]]
#data[0] will return ["list", "in","a list"]
#data[0][0] will return "list"
#remember that lists starts with '0' -> data[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> data=[["why","why","hello"],["why","why","bell"],["why","hi","sllo"],["why","cry","hello"]]
>>> y = []
>>> for subData in data:
        for dataItem in subData:
            if dataItem == "hello":
                y.append(subData)
>>> y
[['why', 'why', 'hello'], ['why', 'cry', 'hello']]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
filter(lambda x : x[-1] =="hello",[["why","why","hello"],["why","why","bell"],["why","hi","sllo"],["why","cry","hello"]])
```

OR

```
reduce(lambda x,y : x + [y] if y[-1]=="hello" else x ,[["why","why","hello"],["why","why","bell"],["why","hi","sllo"],["why","cry","hello"]],[])
```

OR

```
[i for i in [["why","why","hello"],["why","why","bell"],["why","hi","sllo"],["why","cry","hello"]] if i[-1]=="hello"]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data=[["why","why","hello"],["why","why","bell"],["why","hi","sllo"],["why","cry","hello"]]

for word_set in data[:]:
    if word_set[-1]!= "hello":
        data.remove(word_set)
print(data)
```

Don't iterate the origin data,but make a duplicate(data[:]). Because when remove items from list, the index of item will change.`["why","why","bell"]` in list index is 1. when it's removed from data. `["why","hi","sllo"]` in data index will be 1. The next iteration index is 2, so `["why","hi","sllo"]`  is passed and checks `["why","cry","hello"]`.

Comment: Please add some comment as to why you think this code is the answer, as it stands, this answer is not very useful.